# Preserving the position while searching

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I need to make elasticsearch query to work with multiple words. I am using `edgeNgram tokenizer` to support autocompletion feature and I am using query_string for searching.

#### Document

```
{
   "title":"Gold digital cinema",
   "region":"Mumbai"
}
{
  "title":"cine park",
  "region":"Mumbai"
}
{
  "title":"Premier Gold",
  "region":"mumbai"
}
```

#### Query

```
{
  "query": {
  "bool": {
    "should": [
               {
                 "query_string": {
                     "fields": [
                                "title",
                                "region"
                           ],
                    "query":"gold cine"
                  }
               },
               {
                "fuzzy": {  
                  "title": {
                            "value":"gold cine",
                            "min_similarity": 0.5,
                            "max_expansions": 50,
                            "prefix_length": 0
                           }
                         }
               }
             ]
          }
       }
}
```

When I search for gold cine, I need `"title":"Gold digital cinema"` to be in the top results. But I am getting `"title":"cine park"` and `"title":"Premier Gold"` in top.

Is there any way to preserve position while searching?
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

```
{
    "query":{
        "bool":{
            "should":[{
               "query_string":{
                "fields":["title.default_title^10",
                            "title.ngrams_front^2",
                             "title.ngrams_back"],
                                "query":"gold cine",
                                 "boost":2  
                               }
                      },
    { 
        "function_score":{
                   "query":{
                     "query_string":{
                        "fields":["region"],
                        "query":"MUMBAI"
                       }            
                   },
                     "functions":[{
                                    "script_score":{
                                        "script":"_score + 0.6"}    
                                }
                                ],
                                "score_mode":"max",
                                "boost_mode":"avg"
                           }
                      }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boost](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost-field.html#mapping-boost-field) to pull up the data on top..

```
{
"query": {
"bool": {
"should": [
           {
             "query_string": {
                 "fields": [
                            "title",
                            "region"
                       ],
                "query":"gold cine",
                "boost": 3
              }
           },
           {
            "fuzzy": {  
              "title": {
                        "value":"gold cine",
                        "min_similarity": 0.5,
                        "max_expansions": 50,
                        "prefix_length": 0
                       }
                     }
           }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

If you use version 1.0.0.and above you should use [function score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#query-dsl-function-score-query).

HOpe it helps..!

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I tried boosting as u specified. It s giving same result as before. I tried with function_score query but it is affecting other document's result

Comment: @@BlackPOP,I updated the code using function_score query.. But still I am not getting as expected. If you don mind can please tell how can i achieve it.?.